# How to navigate to the previous page in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, back

I'm trying to simulate the function of the hardware back button on a button created by me, I have this in my event click:

```
base.OnBackButtonPressed();
```

But this doesn't work, I put a breakpoint in the override function "OnBackButtonPressed" and it doesn't get to this point. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Try `App.Current.Mainpage.Navigation.PopAsync()`

Comment: It already works correctly, only a small note instead of **PopAsync** is **PopModalAsync**, this way everything works correctly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `PopAsync` or `PopModalAsync` depends on how you pushed the page into your navigation object. Note that `PopModalAsync` will work only when you've used the `PushModalAsync`